# Flutter plugin - How to deregister Lifecycle listeners?

Tags: android, flutter, android-lifecycle, flutter-plugin

I am trying to implement a Flutter plugin and so I am checking the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/plugins/activity/ActivityAware.html#onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(io.flutter.embedding.engine.plugins.activity.ActivityPluginBinding)) for **ActivityAware**

And for **onDetached** it says this:

> void onDetachedFromActivity()
> This plugin has been detached from an Activity.
> Detachment can occur for a number of reasons.

> The app is no longer visible and the Activity instance has been destroyed.
> The FlutterEngine that this plugin is connected to has been detached from its FlutterView.
> This ActivityAware plugin has been removed from its FlutterEngine.
> By the end of this method, the Activity that was made available in onAttachedToActivity(ActivityPluginBinding) is no longer valid.

> Any references to the associated Activity or ActivityPluginBinding should be cleared.

> Any Lifecycle listeners that were registered in onAttachedToActivity(ActivityPluginBinding) or onReattachedToActivityForConfigChanges(ActivityPluginBinding) should be deregistered here to avoid a possible memory leak and other side effects.

How do I actually deregister listeners?
Let's say this is my **onAttachedToActivity**.

```
override fun onAttachedToActivity(binding: ActivityPluginBinding) {
  currentActivity = binding.activity
  binding.addRequestPermissionsResultListener(this)
```

}

What do I put inside my **onDetached** to clean everything up?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `binding.removeRequestPermissionsResultListener(this)` inside `onDetachedFromActivity()`

More info: https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/embedding/engine/plugins/activity/ActivityPluginBinding.html#removeRequestPermissionsResultListener(io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.RequestPermissionsResultListener)